# Error with linux pyodbc connection "Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client11.0'"

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, linux

I have an issue with trying to connect to a SQL database using python inside of a linux container environment. I'm running into the below error when pyodbc tries to connect with a SQL by finding drivers.

`sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client11.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

After looking into it, it seems like pyodbc cannot find the following:

```
odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/gtx914/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

When I double checked, these .ini files do not exist in my linux environment. I'm unsure as to why the pip install pyodbc and uixodbc didn't install the correct dependencies to find the driver. Does anyone here know of a workaround? One caveat is that I'm unable to use any sudo commands as I don't have root access in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

The ODBC driver *itself* is not pip-installable.  You need to install it into your OS or container using apt-get (or similar), per the instructions here:

[Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)